# SOLR cross server joins

Tags: join, solr

We use joins in `SOLR`

```
({!join from=id to=another_id fromIndex=core_index} )
```

I would like to ask what happens if we put one core in one server and another core in another server.

Does `SOLR` allow for cross server joins?

thx in advance

Answer (score 0):

As I know, solr join, will work only between cores. See the Limitation section, [here](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/Join).